# How to join 3 tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 3 tables:

> tbl_events       --> primary key = event_id
>
> tbl_event_bids   --> (event_id is in it no primary key)
>
> tbl_users        --> primary key = u_id

I want to get these fields:

> tbl_events       --> added_date
>
> tbl_events       --> bid_end_date
>
> tbl_events       --> event_date
>
> tbl_event_bids   --> bid_amount
>
> tbl_users        --> u_fname
>
> tbl_users        --> u_lname

there is no any error but the array is empty. Is there any error in this code? Please help...

```
public function get_confirmed_events($loged_user_id){

    $this->db->select(' tbl_events.event_name,
                        tbl_events.added_date,
                        tbl_events.bid_end_date,                            
                        tbl_events.event_date,

                        tbl_event_bids.bid_amount,

                        tbl_users.u_fname,
                        tbl_users.u_lname');

    $this->db->where('tbl_events.u_id', $loged_user_id);
    $this->db->where('tbl_events.closed_bid', 'N');

    $this->db->where('tbl_event_bids.bid_statues', 'W');        

    $this->db->join('tbl_event_bids', 'tbl_events.event_id = tbl_event_bids.event_id');
    $this->db->join('tbl_users', 'tbl_events.u_id = tbl_users.u_id');

    $data = $this->db->get('tbl_events');

    $confirmed_result = $data->result();

    return $confirmed_result;


}
```

Comment: join first the table before using where statement.. if you want to join the 3rd table.. just add another $this->db->join('') to connect

Comment: Try checking what `print $this->db->last_query()` prints after your query have ran. I found that it's easier to debug the sql queries and then port back changes to code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
public function get_confirmed_events($loged_user_id){
$this->db->select(' tbl_events.event_name,
                    tbl_events.added_date,
                    tbl_events.bid_end_date,                            
                    tbl_events.event_date,
                    tbl_event_bids.bid_amount,
                    tbl_users.u_fname,
                    tbl_users.u_lname');      
$this->db->join('tbl_event_bids', 'tbl_events.event_id = tbl_event_bids.event_id','LEFT');
$this->db->join('tbl_users', 'tbl_events.u_id = tbl_users.u_id','LEFT');
$this->db->where('tbl_events.u_id', $loged_user_id);
$this->db->where('tbl_events.closed_bid', 'N');
$this->db->where('tbl_event_bids.bid_statues', 'W'); 
$data = $this->db->get('tbl_events');
$confirmed_result = $data->result();
return $confirmed_result;
}
```

I have used the `LEFT JOIN` if want to join with other you can specify it in the third parameter of `join()` also see your query how it looks like `echo  $this->db->last_query();`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using joins, you have to use FROM, for primary table

```
public function get_confirmed_events($loged_user_id){

$this->db->select(' tbl_events.event_name,
                    tbl_events.added_date,
                    tbl_events.bid_end_date,                            
                    tbl_events.event_date,

                    tbl_event_bids.bid_amount,

                    tbl_users.u_fname,
                    tbl_users.u_lname');
$this->db->from('tbl_events');
$this->db->where('tbl_events.u_id', $loged_user_id);
$this->db->where('tbl_events.closed_bid', 'N');

$this->db->where('tbl_event_bids.bid_statues', 'W');        

$this->db->join('tbl_event_bids', 'tbl_events.event_id = tbl_event_bids.event_id','left');
$this->db->join('tbl_users', 'tbl_events.u_id = tbl_users.u_id','left');

$data = $this->db->get();

$confirmed_result = $data->result();

return $confirmed_result;
```

}

I hope it will help you.